# Winforms constructor time sequence bug?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following Winforms hierarchy.

```
Form ==> AForm ==> BForm
```

And there is a null-able member `int? X;` defined in `FormA`. And in `FormB`, there is the following code.

```
public partial class FormA: Form
{
    public int? X { get; set; }
    public FormA(int? x) { X = x }
....

public partial class FormB: FormA, IFormAView
{
    public FormB()
    {
        AsyncCall(() => 
        {
            int z = X ?? 0;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("X: " + X.ToString() + " z: " + z.ToString());
            return z;
        }

public static T GetForm<T>(int? x)
{
    T form = new T();
    form.X = x;
    form.Show();
}
GetForm<FormB>(100);
```

`X` was never be assigned null or zero. I am trying to close and open the form `FormB`. Occasionally `z` is zero (maybe once every 10 times). I set a conditional break which breaks when `z==0` on the line `return z`.

When the break point is hit. The debug write

```
    X:  z: 0
```

even the debug shows the FormA:X is not zero.

Comment: Now it's apparent.  You're calling the FomrB constructor (which kicks off your AsyncCall).  You *then* call `form.X = x;`.  Depending on how fast the AsyncCall completes, it may or may not have a value when it is processing X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are invoking code on another thread to test X (using AsyncCall and "X ??") that code may or may not be run before or after X is assigned in the FormA constructor.

i.e. if you stop using AsyncCall, you should get consistent results.

Answer (score 2):

In FormA, X is a [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) int property, which defaults to `null`.  You are never calling the `public FormA(int? x)` base constructor from your `public FormB()` constructor, so X never gets set to anything else.

Since you are setting the value of X after you call FormB's constructor (which invokces the AsyncCall), you will run into timing issues, since the AsyncCall could compelte before or after you set `form.X = x;` in your GetForm function.

If you want your AsyncCall to still be an AsyncCall, you should update FormB()'s constructor to be as follows:

public FormB(int? x) : base(x)
{
    // ...

and then update GetForm as follows (note the where clause, this lets us know that T is at least derived from FromA, so it has a constructor that takes in an int?):

```
public static T GetForm<T>(int? x) where T : FormA
{
     T form = new T(x);
     form.Show();
}
```

Comment: Where's your `FormB(int)` constructor?  It's not listed in the code above, and it's possible that that doesn't cal your parameterless `FormB()` constructor, or that it doesn't call the base constructor.

Comment: I've updated the question. The form is created using a static method.